# Page Footer not following automatic spacing

Tags: html, css

I've been developing a website with a friend and I have a little problem.
We need to set our footer manually in the page with `position:relative` and `margin-top` to fix it because it isn't following the last `<tr<` end. 
I've been trying to fix this problem around 3 weeks and I'm really frustrated with this... 
The **"footer"** `<tr>` is following the **"right-column"** `<tr>`, but even I if I try to remove it, it tries to get aligned with a tr in the top of the page instead of the **"container"** `<tr>`
I'm posting the last lines of the code here, but since I have no idea of what is causing this, I'm sending below the website link itself. 
My website is **onlinewinxclub.com/centro-web/test.php**

```
<tr id="container">
    <td id="container_left_column">
        <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 11px; margin-left: 15px;">
            <iframe id="ranking_iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="pages/Iframes/Access_guests.php"></iframe>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td id="container_middle_column" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <table id="content_videobox" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="">
                    <td id="content_videobox_firstcolumn" rowspan="3">
                        <div id="content_videobox_iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" volume="0"><video
                                class="file" preload="metadata"
                                poster="././medias/images/Video_Thumbs/happy2021thumb.png"
                                src="././medias/videos/Happy_2021.mp4" data-overlay="1"></video></div>
                    </td>

                    <td id="content_videobox_secondcolumn">
                        <h2>
                            <span class="video-title" id="content_videobox_videotitle"
                                style="text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #560027;">Happy New Year!</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p style="position:relative; top: 150px;">
                            <span class="video-description" id="content_videobox_videotext"
                                style="text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #560027;">2021 arrived. Your favorite Winx fairies and
                                specialists are hoping it will be better than the last one. The witches? Not
                                sure.</span>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                    <td id="content_videobox_firstcolumn2">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="">
                    <img onclick="javascript:Previous();" class="previous"
                        style="position: relative; top: 274px; left: 541px; cursor: pointer;"
                        src="././medias/images/arrow_left.png"
                        onmouseover="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_left_hover.png';"
                        onmouseout="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_left.png';">
                    <img onclick="javascript:Next();" class="next"
                        style="position: relative; top: 274px; left: 625px; cursor: pointer;"
                        src="././medias/images/arrow_right.png"
                        onmouseover="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_right_hover.png';"
                        onmouseout="this.src='././medias/images/arrow_right.png';">
                    <td id="content_videobox_secondcolumn2" style="text-align: center">
                        <span class="video-number"
                            style="color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; height: bold; text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #560027;">
                            1/4 </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="content_mininews_frame">
            <iframe id="content_mininews_iframe" frameborder="0" src="pages/Mininews/NewsContentV2.php">Browser not
                compatible.</iframe>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td id="container_right_column" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <div id="content_horoscope_iframe">
            <iframe id="content_horoscope_iframe" frameborder="0" src="pages/Tips.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled="">Browser
                not compatible.</iframe>
        </div>
        <iframe style="position: relative;width: 703px;height: 219px;margin-left: -467px;margin-top: -91px;"
            frameborder="0" src="pages/Iframes/Download.php" data-ruffle-polyfilled="">Browser not compatible!</iframe>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr id="footer">
    <td id="footer_content" colspan="2">
        <hr style="margin-top: auto; position: relative;">
        <div style="margin-top: auto; position: relative;">
            <img id="footer_rainbow_img" src="././medias/images/rainbow_logo_small.jpg">
            <p id="footer_text">Winx Club™ a series created and produced by Iginio Straffi and Rainbow S.r.l<br>
                © 2011-2021 Winx Club Online - Unofficial WinxClub.com inspirated by the old official website
            </p>
        </div>​
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you aren't targetting old, no-longer-supported browsers, you could use CSS grid for the layout, e.g. [Holy Grail Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-grid-starter-layouts/).

Comment: I really like this idea, because it get rid of all the tables we have to define the layout. But I'm afraid this isn't going to be applicable to us, since it would imply rewriting all the pages we currently have on the website (over 20) and they're literally done, with only the footer needing a fix.

Answer (score 2):

first remove the

#container - position absolute

I think you are positioning it because of the iframe. why don't you add iframe with the `.container_middle_column`? you can add td and give a width or create new table inside the td, because you are using table. And make `#footer - posision relative`. If you use bootsrap it will be easy more than this.